# getActivePage().showView() pass model

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-emf, emf

using the EMF to start another view I would do this:

`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("viewid")`

thing is, what if I want to pass some object through as well, is there a way to do this?

EDIT

I can just create the view like this: `SomeView sv = new SomeView(objecttopass);`
but then how would I start the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** try and call your view constructor yourself that will not work.

`showView` returns you the view part that was shown:

```
IViewPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("viewid");
```

If the view is your code you can then cast that to your view class and call a method to set the data:

```
SomeView myPart = (SomeView)part;

myPart.setData(objecttopass);
```